# PHP, get data from the database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to retrieve data from a database with PHP and show it on a website.

This code does not work correctly.  I want to display all cars that are Chevy on my database.

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","myusername",
"mypassword","database");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
    echo("Could not connect" .
      mysqli_connect_error($db) . "</p>");
    exit(" ");
}

$result = mysqli_query($query);

if(!$result){
  echo "<p> Could not retrieve at this time, please come back soon</p>" .   
    mysqli_error($dv);
}

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cars where carType = 'Chevy' AND active = 1")
  or die(mysql_error());

echo"<table border cellpadding=3>";
while($row= mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
{
  echo"<tr>";
  echo"<th>Name:</th> <td>".$row['name'] . "</td> ";
  echo"<th>ImagePath:</th> <td>".$row['imagePath'] . " </td></tr>";
  echo"<th>Description:</th> <td>".$row['description'] . "</td> ";
  echo"<th>Price:</th> <td>".$row['Price'] . " </td></tr>";
}
echo"</table>";
?>
```

How do I get data from the database with PHP?

Comment: you are not querying to database so it wont give you result. What are you getting error/warning if you remove the `@` before `mysql_fetch_array` ?

Comment: i edited my question and modified my code with your suggestions. i kept mysqli though. I am new with php and mysql so I am not sure if I am doing this right

Comment: you shoul either use mysql_* or mysqli ...what you doing is making the connection for mysqli and querying by mysql_* so it wont work try the code in answer and see the link at the end of answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**you are not querying to database so it wont give you result**

this is how  it works

1. connect to the database by [`mysql_connect()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

   mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
2. than select the database like  [`mysql_select_db()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php)

   mysql_select_db("Database_Name") or die(mysql_error());
3. you need to use [`mysql_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

like

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM cars where carType = 'chevy' AND active = 1";
 $result =mysql_query($query); //you can also use here or die(mysql_error());
```

to see if error

4. and than [`mysql_fetch_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

   if($result){
   while($row= mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
   //result
   }
   }

so try

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cars where carType = 'chevy' AND active = 1")  or die(mysql_error()); 
 echo"<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
 while($row= mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
    echo"<tr>"; 
    echo"<th>Name:</th> <td>".$row['name'] . "</td> "; 
    echo"<th>ImagePath:</th> <td>".$row['imagePath'] . " </td></tr>"; 
    echo"<th>Description:</th> <td>".$row['description'] . "</td> "; 
    echo"<th>Price:</th> <td>".$row['Price'] . " </td></tr>"; 
 } 
 echo"</table>"; 
 ?>
```

### **Note:**

`Mysql_*` function are deprecated so use `PDO` or `MySQLi` instead . I would suggest PDO its lot more easier and simple to read you can learn here [PDO Tutorial for MySQL Developers][5] also check [Pdo for beginners ( why ? and how ?)][6]

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
 // Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("hostname", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("Database_Name") or die(mysql_error()); 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cars where cars.carType = 'chevy' AND cars.active = 1") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 Print "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
 while($row= mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 Print "<tr>"; 
 Print "<th>Name:</th> <td>".$row['name'] . "</td> "; 
 Print "<th>ImagePath:</th> <td>".$row['imagePath'] . " </td></tr>"; 
 Print "<th>Description:</th> <td>".$row['description'] . "</td> "; 
 Print "<th>Price:</th> <td>".$row['Price'] . " </td></tr>"; 
 } 
 Print "</table>"; 
 ?>
```