# Renama file in folder with values from table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I  learn about the `rename()` function in PHP:

```
<?php
rename ("/folder/01/file.ext", "/folder/01/newfile.ext");
?>
```

I have the following problems, the number `01` is the `id` file from `mytable`. And, I want to rename old name with value of `number_phone` from  `mytable`.

How to do that?

Comment: _How to do that?_ What exactly is your question? Do you get some errors? What is stopping you from implementing the fnction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP, get data from the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656911/php-get-data-from-the-database)

Comment: @hahardyan please share your code or an error. Thanks

Comment: It will be much easier for us to help you if you add your attempt, any error message you're getting, the database structure and an example of the expected output. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just fill in your arguments in the `rename` function:

```
rename("/folder/01/file.ext", "/folder/${mytable['id']}/${mytable['number_phone']}.ext");
```

The `$` operator in PHP performs value expansion in a string.

Comment: I think the question is way to unclear to be answered. This might be what the OP is looking for, but it's still just a stab in the dark.